# rails 4 Перевод ошибок валидации accepts_nested_attributes_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Как можно перевести название полей в i18n(ru.yml) файле поля для ошибок в accepts_nested_attributes_for?
Модель Company связана с Phone, так же есть у Company accepts_nested_attributes_for :phones. Вроде бы все переводит в хелпере, но именно при валидации выдает "Company phones phone не может быть пустым".

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :phones, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :phones
end

class Phone < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :phone, presence: true
  belongs_to :company
end
```

Comment: Вот! Ещё одна причина ими не пользоваться и вместо них сделать аккуратный и красивый form object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Официальная документация](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models) - вы можете добавлять в locales переводы models attributes, например:

```
# {Rails.root}/config/locales/ru.yml
ru:
 activerecord:
  attributes:
   user/gender:
    female: "Женщина"
    male: "Мужчина"
```

Если не помогло, то вот [решение такой же проблемы](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14176433/rails3-i18n-accepts-nested-attributes-for-how-to-translate)

Но я бы еще сделал валидацию на стороне клиента. Во-первых, чтобы юзер не ждал ответа сервера после отправки формы, а во-вторых, если делать валидацию на js, то вы можете как угодно стилизовать и оформить все это дело

Comment: Пробовал ранее по гайдам - не работало, попробовал еще раз и вуаля! заработало. Благодарю.